# How can I swap two bits starting from MSB?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, swap

I'm looking for a way to swap 2 bits at a given position but counting starts from MSB(most significant bit) to LSB (least significant bit).
Lets say i have position p1 = 0 and p2 = 2 and my number is **1000** = 8  . The result should be
**0010**  .

I tried this piece of code but it swaps the bits starting from LSB to MSB . How do I "reverse" the process?

```
    unsigned int bit1 =  (num >> p1) & 1;
    unsigned int bit2 =  (num >> p2) & 1;
    unsigned int x = (bit1 ^ bit2);
      x = (x << p1) | (x << p2);
     result = num ^ x;
```

Comment: `num >> (31 - p1)` ?

Comment: The reason bits are conventionally 'numbered' from right to left is that there will always be a "bit 0" regardless of the width of the datatype. You could consider "inverting" the value by subtracting values of p1 & p2 from, in this case, 32-1...

Comment: it didn't work..

Comment: By MSB, do you mean the most significant bit in the format (i.e., in a 32-bit unsigned integer, the bit with value 2^31) or the most significant bit set in the particular number (i.e., for the value 8 in a 32-bit unsigned integer, the bit with value 2^3)?

Comment: Second case (MSB in particular number) . Also my numbers should be represented on 4 bits max.

Comment: Bit of a nuisance asking for help but omitting details like "4 bits max" and redefining "MSB". What is your idea of an MSB, in 4 bits, for the value "0x0"?? 0x01 could only be "swapped" to negative values. Waste of time... Downvoiting...

Comment: Agreed. Only now saying “4 bits max” with a shifting MSB left me feeling like the casino duped me into playing a shell game — and cheated.

Answer (score 1):

By your example, I will assume you mean to start numbering bits from the MSB of the number value. That is, given:

```
00010100
   ↑
   msb == most significant bit in the number
```

In that case, you need a way to count the bit index of the MSB. There are actually processor instructions you can use to do that, and both MSVC and GCC (and Clang) provide special functions to access that functionality...

...but you don’t need that. Instead, just write yourself a function:

```
int index_of_msb( unsigned long value )
{
  ...
}
```

Remember that you can shift a number down by one bit at a time. As long as the number is not zero, you have at least one set bit left.

```
  1 0 1 0 0 0
→   1 0 1 0 0  (1 shift)
→     1 0 1 0  (2 shifts)
→       1 0 1  (3 shifts)
→         1 0  (4 shifts)
→           1  (5 shifts)
→           0
```

Five shifts → bit 5 is MSB.

Now you can convert your bit positions to the standard shift offsets.

```
p1 = p_msb - p1;
p2 = p_msb - p2;
```

What remains to do is use your standard bit operators to swap the two bit values.

Answer (score 0):

Four bits is small enough that you can use a 256-byte table:

```
unsigned char SwapBits(unsigned char number, int p0, int p1)
{
    static const unsigned char Table[16][4][4] = {
{ { 0,  0,  0,  0}, { 0,  0,  0,  0}, { 0,  0,  0,  0}, { 0,  0,  0,  0} },
{ { 1,  0,  0,  0}, { 0,  0,  0,  0}, { 0,  0,  0,  0}, { 0,  0,  0,  0} },
{ { 2,  1,  0,  0}, { 1,  2,  2,  2}, { 0,  2,  2,  2}, { 0,  2,  2,  2} },
{ { 3,  3,  1,  1}, { 3,  3,  2,  2}, { 1,  2,  3,  3}, { 1,  2,  3,  3} },
{ { 4,  2,  1,  0}, { 2,  4,  4,  4}, { 1,  4,  4,  4}, { 0,  4,  4,  4} },
{ { 5,  3,  5,  1}, { 3,  5,  6,  5}, { 5,  6,  5,  4}, { 1,  5,  4,  5} },
{ { 6,  6,  3,  2}, { 6,  6,  5,  4}, { 3,  5,  6,  6}, { 2,  4,  6,  6} },
{ { 7,  7,  7,  3}, { 7,  7,  7,  5}, { 7,  7,  7,  6}, { 3,  5,  6,  7} },
{ { 8,  4,  2,  1}, { 4,  8,  8,  8}, { 2,  8,  8,  8}, { 1,  8,  8,  8} },
{ { 9,  5,  3,  9}, { 5,  9,  9, 12}, { 3,  9,  9, 10}, { 9, 12, 10,  9} },
{ {10,  6, 10,  3}, { 6, 10, 12, 10}, {10, 12, 10,  9}, { 3, 10,  9, 10} },
{ {11,  7, 11, 11}, { 7, 11, 13, 14}, {11, 13, 11, 11}, {11, 14, 11, 11} },
{ {12, 12,  6,  5}, {12, 12, 10,  9}, { 6, 10, 12, 12}, { 5,  9, 12, 12} },
{ {13, 13,  7, 13}, {13, 13, 11, 13}, { 7, 11, 13, 14}, {13, 13, 14, 13} },
{ {14, 14, 14,  7}, {14, 14, 14, 11}, {14, 14, 14, 13}, { 7, 11, 13, 14} },
{ {15, 15, 15, 15}, {15, 15, 15, 15}, {15, 15, 15, 15}, {15, 15, 15, 15} },
    };
    return Table[number][p0][p1];
}
```